# php loop and main page

Tags: php

I am trying to program a Flat File PHP Dictionary (English -> Spanish).
I've got this up to now:

```
<?php

$data =
'car;coche
cat;gato
fat;gordo
far;lejos';

    if($data) {

    $line = explode("\n", $data);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {

        $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);

        if($_GET['word'] == $item[0]) { echo"<div>" . $item[0] . "</div> <div>" . $item[1] . "</div>"; }
        else {echo MAIN PAGE;}
    }
}

?>
```

It is perfect because it opens a loop of pages in one php file:

e.g. `http://localhost/?word=fat`  prints "Fat Gordo"

My problem is when creating the main page http://localhost. I tried with `else{ echo "MAIN PAGE";}` but, wherever I place it, it prints "MAIN PAGEMAIN PAGEMAIN PAGE".

Any help?

Comment: So... Code that's *different* from what you're showing us is producing unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you are looping through every line in `$data`. Whatever the outcome of the if expression is, after that it just goes on to the next iteration and runs the if statement again.

So if you add the `} else { echo "mainpage"` to your if, it will echo `mainpage` everytime when `$_GET['word']` doesn't match `$item[0]` (which obviously at every line if `$_GET['word']` is not defined)

To avoid this you can add something like this:

```
if($data && !empty($_GET['word'])) {
   (...)
} else {
   echo "mainpage";
}
```

If you have a big dictionary it's also good to break you loop once you have found a matching word:

```
if($_GET['word'] == $item[0]) { 
  echo "<div>" . $item[0] . "</div> <div>" . $item[1] . "</div>";
  break;
}
```